# Problema con Start y el valor de una variable

Tags: java, genexus

Tengo un problema, tengo un web panel en el que el evento Start se ejecuta cada vez que se altera el valor de uno de sus campos, el problema es que el evento start tiene un código muy denso(y lento) y no es necesario que se ejecute más que al cargar el panel. 
he definido una bandera para conocer cuando ya se ha ejecutado el evento start la primera vez, el asunto es que siempre que se ejecuta el evento start la variable se ha reiniciado previamente. he intentado hacer lo mismo de muchas maneras diferentes pero no he tenido resultados positivos ¿alguien me aporta una idea de como solucionar el problema?

Comment: Hola buenas, sin código es muy difícil ayudarte. Si no es el codigo del `start`, pon al menos el de la bandera. Por lo que dices, la bandera no es estática, y por eso pierde el valor. Guarda la variable como estática.